# How to connect two truffle instances?

Tags: dapp-development, truffle, connections

How can we connect two truffle applications with each other? E.g., if we have two metacoin applications, how can these two communicate with each other?

Answer (score 4):

By using the same blockchain you can interact with a single contract. Make sure that the applications use the same contract address by using for example `var meta = MetaCoin.at("0x1234...")`. You can find out where the contract is deployed with `MetaCoin.deployed_address`.
The only challenge is to tell the second application where the deployed address of the starting application is. Simplest is to write it into a file.

Answer (score 2):

To establish the connection between two applications, you need a smart contract. This smart contract will be deployed at one end .
The deploying application will use it as `contractname.deployed()` to create an instance of contract.
As we know that to access any contract on the blockchain, we need :

1. Contract's AbiDefinition
2. Contract Address

Second application will only compile the contract. Thus abiDefinition will be available to second app. And contract address will be provided using `contractname.at(contractaddress)`in the application.
Thus your both applications can communicate.Let me know any further query.